# How to create sales buckets in dax/powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table like so:

```
Client   Sales

Julie    $100
Alex     $1000
Ben      $500
```

I want to create two sales buckets, 0-100$ and 100-1000$. I want to create a table that organizes the above data like so:

```
Bucket      Total Sales
0-100$        $100
100-1000$     $1500
```

I am new to dax and I am at a loss on how to do this. This is what I have so far but it isn't spitting out the expected result:

```
sales = SWITCH (
         TRUE,
         'salestable'[sales]<= 100, 'salestable'[sales],
         'salestable'[sales] > 100 && <= 1000, 'salestable'[sales],
)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Have you got the answer for this question?

Answer (score 0):

You need a calculated column or a measure lets create a calculated column inside the table as below. I suggest you to create a calculated column.

```
sales bucket = 
IF (
    'Sales Targets'[Target] <= 1000
        && 'Sales Targets'[Target] > 100,
    "100-1000$",
    IF ( 'Sales Targets'[Target] <= 100, "0-100$", BLANK () )
)
```